# How to stop scrolling in videos during playback on screen touch on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video

When I play a video in fullscreen on the iPhone, touching the screen and moving your finger horizontally changes the position in the video.

Very often, that happens by accident for me, since the hand with which I am holding the device happens to touch the screen a bit or I want to remove a dustparticle from the screen. With the old player (few updates ago), I could do that.

Is there a way to switch off this functionality, I experience it as very annoying.

*Update:*

Using iPhone SE second generation, iOS 16.4.1. Video is played from brave-browser on the YouTube-website in fullscreen- I think this is just the standard video player of iOS. I think the feature is called swiping: When you hold your finger on the video on by moving the finger you can change the position in the video.

Comment: What do you mean by it "changes the position in the video"? Also, what iOS version are you running? From where is the video being played (app, website from Safari/Chrome, etc.)?

Comment: @Thinkr Photos app will shuttle the playhead within the video as if one is pressing the fast forward (or fast backward) on a video stream.

Comment: @IconDaemon AFAIK, there is no fast forward/backward option in Photos on iPhone when reading a video.

Comment: The finger touch replicates the actions of FF and FB buttons you see on streaming apps (particularly on Apple TV remotes) or on DVD players and VCR players. I didn't mention DVDs and VCRs because most people have no idea what I'm writing about.

Answer (score 1):

From [Adjust how iPhone responds to your touch](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/touch-accommodations-iph77bcdd132/ios) :

> 1. Go to **Settings  > Accessibility > Touch > Touch Accommodations**, then turn on Touch Accommodations.
> 2. You can configure your iPhone to do any of the following :
>
>    - *Respond to touches of a certain duration:* Turn on **Hold Duration**, then tap the Decrement button or the Increment button to adjust the duration. (The default is 0.10 seconds.)
>    - *Prevent unintended swipe gestures:* To increase the amount of movement required before a swipe gesture begins, tap **Swipe Gestures**, turn on Swipe Gestures, then adjust required movement.
>    - […]

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

[image: Screenshot of the Touch Accomodations settings (annotated)]

---

##### Further explanations :

In this case (screenshot), pressing a button will only be registered if you keep your finger on it for at least 0.15 seconds. You also need to set the parameter in Swipe Gestures to Standard, 2X, 4X, 6X or 8X. This means that (if you have set the parameter to anything other than Standard) you will have to swipe 2X, 4X, 6X or 8X more on the screen than you would normally do in order to perform the scroll gesture you want.

Of course, this will always be the case if you don't disable it manually. To disable it, triple-click the Home/Side button (depending on the iPhone model you're using) and deselect the Touch Accommodations option. (The option will be there automatically, no need to configure anything in Settings > Accessibility > Accessibility Shortcut or anywhere else).

**Note :** You will not see the Swipe Gestures parameter if Hold Duration is not enabled.

Comment: Very usefeul, thanks! From this information I take that what I am looking for is not possible, to switch off the swipe feature, without switching on "Touch accommodations", which gives me an overlay over the screen.

Comment: @MathiasBader Well you can switch Swipe Gestures on and off while having Touch Accommodations off, you only have to have Hold Duration on to access the Swipe Gestures parameters. However, none of those parameters will work if Touch Accomodations isn't enabled. It is indeed quite annoying and could be an interesting feature [to propose](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) - Making possible to activate/de-activate singe options withing Touch Accommodations (and have it working).

Comment: @MathiasBader But you can still enable the wanted feature (Hold Duration and/or Swipe Gestures) while watching a video and disable it after (see answer for how).

Comment: I tried this feature: It only applies if "Touch accomodation" is on, but this changes the complete behavior of the phone, which I don't want. I was hoping I could just switch of swiping in the video player.

Comment: @MathiasBader I'm afraid it's not yet possible.